# Why does script to run MySQLdump on each line of file gives error "command not found"?

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line, command, command-line-interface

Performing automated database backups for starters and testing commands.  I've found for performing an action on each line of a text file via BASH CLI is something to the effect of:

```
# while read line; do
      COMMAND $line
  done
```

I've created a list of the database names file:

```
# mysql -uroot -e "show databases" > databases
```

Then tried the following against the file to see if it would work correctly.

```
# while read line; do 
  "mysqldump -uroot $line > /dbbackups/$line.sql"
  done
```

Seemingly, this would be working correctly but am met with the following error(s):

```
[04:58:46] [root@theia database-backup-testing]# cat databases | while read line ; do "mysqldump -uroot $line > $line.sql" ; done
-bash: mysqldump -uroot Database > Database.sql: command not found
-bash: mysqldump -uroot information_schema > information_schema.sql: command not found
-bash: mysqldump -uroot cphulkd > cphulkd.sql: command not found
```

I am not sure why it is giving command not found, when obviously, the output of the commands seems to be correct.  I have also tried using the absolute path of mysqldump (/usr/bin/mysqldump) but it gives the same error(s).

Can anyone fill me in on why this is happening?

---

EDIT: I found a fix:

The script works if the quotes are removed:

```
# cat databases | 
  while read line; do 
      mysqldump -uroot $line > $line.sql
  done
```

Apparently, the quotes causes it to execute as a string and not a command.

Comment: try "which mysqldump" in bash. "ls + chmod" to make sure "you can  execute mysqldump"

Comment: You need to specify the path to mysqldump.  But why not just use its [`--all-databases`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases) option?

Comment: Using the absolute path, which I've stated above I have already tried, returns the following:
----
-bash: /usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot Database > Database.sql: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script that solves this:
https://github.com/jeevandongre/backup-restore

Comment: Hey Jeeven,  Thanks for that although I take pride in writing my own scripts (helps me learn better!).

Answer (score 0):

> why it is giving command not found

Your quotes are not correct, Try something like this:

```
while read line ; do mysqldump -uroot "$line" > "$line".sql ; done
```

Haven't used [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) so I cant help with the syntax of the specific command.